# VS2013 C intellisense not working properly

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

I've been using VS2010 and switched to VS2013 two weeks ago. I've just noticed that Intellisense's error reporting for C code lacks when compared to VS2010.
Here is an example code to test it.
**File: main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf(1234);
    return 0;
}
```

VS2013's Intellisense doesn't display an error when the code is a C file. But when changing the extension to.cpp, Intellisense detects the error. I've tried resetting settings and updating VS2013 it but it still doesn't work.

How can I make VS2013 show Intellisense errors on C files too.

Comment: Nice observation and thanks for sharing the fact. Now, yes, so what is your question?

Comment: @NatashaDutta, Cleared it up.